# how to set visabilty time to image in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

hi i am doing one app here  when i click button that time i need to display image.that image should be visable in 5sec.after 5 sec after that image should need to be invisable.i trieb but i am not getting after 5 sec how to invisable that image.any one suggest me. i using below code.

```
      Demo1 .class
        public class Demo1 extends Activity {
           /** Called when the activity is first created. */
                 Button b1;
         ImageView i1;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.main);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.homebutton);
     i1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
             b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           i1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }
            });
     }
      }
```

Comment: using Hander.postdelayed(r,5000) you can create this....

Answer (score 0):

use handler.postDelayed method to delay some operation to some time, so for your operation use following:

```
i1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
             b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           i1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           Handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){public void run(){ i1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}, 5000);
         }
            });
```